# How to replace the default logo in NSIS installer?

Tags: installation, nsis, graphical-logo

I would like to replace the default logo in my NSIS installer (see image below), but I cannot find anything about this on the internet. Can it be done?

[image]

Answer (score 48, accepted):

For the sake of completion, this is the full code I used to change the logo (using Anders method) and the executable icon (using CharlesB method). Also included MUI2.nsh as mentioned by Yuri Korolov.

```
!include "MUI2.nsh"

!define MUI_ICON "path\to\icon.ico"
!define MUI_HEADERIMAGE
!define MUI_HEADERIMAGE_BITMAP "path\to\InstallerLogo.bmp"
!define MUI_HEADERIMAGE_RIGHT
```

Comment: I found that the standard bitmap exported by GIMP wouldn't display the `.bmp` file in the header. However if I exported a bitmap from Paint then it would work.

Comment: @icc97 This GIMP's behaviour even today still applies.

Answer (score 28):

put this anywhere in your .nsi (after inclusion of MUI.nsh):

```
!define MUI_ICON path_to_icon_file.ico
```

Answer (score 8):

With MakeNSISW 2.3 only type `Icon`

```
Icon "MyIcon.ico"
```

https://nsis.sourceforge.io/Reference/Icon

Answer (score 4):

MUI_ICON changes the .exe icon and that icon is used by default in the MUI header but if you want to use a specific bitmap in the header you can use MUI_HEADERIMAGE/MUI_HEADERIMAGE_BITMAP

You can find all the Modern UI configuration options [in the docs](http://nsis.sourceforge.net/Docs/Modern%20UI/Readme.html)

Answer (score 4):

You have to include MUI or MUI2 in order to make it work in your script

```
!include "MUI2.nsh"

!define MUI_ICON "icon.ico"
!define MUI_HEADERIMAGE
!define MUI_HEADERIMAGE_BITMAP "header.bmp"
!define MUI_HEADERIMAGE_RIGHT
```